# passing parameters to ng-click's function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angularjs-ng-click

How to pass, so to say, refference to scope's parameter, in ng-click
You can check what I want in this pluner

http://plnkr.co/edit/Em7LiNStICjZA23pSph3?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically, you wouldn't need to do this dynamically as you would have specific `$scope` properties on `inputs` etc.

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0Kcar?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<div class="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <button ng-click="update(1, 'text1');">update text 1</button>
   <button ng-click="update(2, 'text2');">update text 2</button>
    {{text1}} , {{text2}}
<div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.update = function(parameter1, textVar){
      if (parameter1 === 1) {$scope[textVar] = "1"}
      if (parameter1 === 2) {$scope[textVar] = "2"}
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but I think you are mixing some things up. In your code, you are setting a `textVar` variable to either 1 or 2. This variable is never used however.

You'll have to bind the element to a variable on the scope, and then in your update function update the relevant scope variable, for instance:

```
$scope.update = function(button, text) {
  if(button == 1) {
    $scope.text1 = text;
  } else if(button == 2) {
    $scope.text2 = text;
  }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<button ng-click="update(1,'Text for text1');">update text 1</button>
<button ng-click="update(2, 'Text for text2');">update text 2</button>
<span ng-bind="text1"></span>, <span ng-bind="text2"></span>
```